# How to make a customized function in bash file

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc, bash-functions

I am looking for a way to create a customized function in one of the setting files, so that when I open up a new session, the same customized function can be evaluated (or sourced), and I can use the function easily.

I try to create a function to check if `ERROR` exists in my log file, so when I check the log files, I can just type the function name and the log file name. Now I am using grep:`grep ERROR test.txt`

But I want to make it easier because I have a lot of these checks. So I add this line in `.bashrc`:

```
ok(){grep ERROR $filename}
```

and when I use the function, I expected to type: `ok test.txt`
and it should give me the ERROR lines, if any.

However, after I evaluated the `.bashrc` file, I got an error message:

```
-bash: .bashrc: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

After I typed: `ok test.txt`, it provides:

```
-bash: ok: command not found
```

Can someone help me with this customized function? Or should I paste my code in another setting file like `.bashrc-profile`?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell is just really picky about the syntax and whitespace with the `{ ... }` construct. These two ways to set up that function would work:

```
ok() { grep ERROR $filename; }
ok() {
    grep ERROR $filename
}
```

Regarding braces `{ .. }` vs. parenthesis `( .. )`, [Bash's manual states that](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping):

> The semicolon (or newline) following *list* is required.

and

> The braces are reserved words, so they must be separated from the *list* by blanks or other shell metacharacters.

*List* refers to the commands inside the braces, and all of this applies where ever `{ ... }` is used, but functions are probably the most common place.

Also, if you want to be able to give the filename as a parameter to the function, use `$1` inside it. i.e. `ok() { grep ERROR "$1"; }` could be used as `ok test.txt`.

Comment: Thank you so much @ilkkachu. I tried all your suggested scripts. The first two took a long time to run, which shouldn't, because the test file is really small with less than 100 characters. The last one `ok() { grep ERROR "$1"; } works perfect. Do you know why the first two run forever?

Comment: `grep ERROR $filename` with `$filename` unset will expand to and run `grep ERROR`, which waits for keyboard input. It doesn't just "take a long time to run", it will never terminate unless you type and end with a flush (usually Ctrl-D).

Comment: @Counter10000, a command like `grep ERROR $filename` would expand the variable `filename`, and run grep on that file. But if the variable is not set, `grep` doesn't get a filename, and starts reading standard input, i.e. the terminal instead. `grep ERROR "$filename"` (with quotes) would give an error instead, since it'd pass `grep` an _empty_ string as argument, and that's an invalid filename

Comment: @dhag .@ilkkachu Thank you both. I thought when I put a dollar sign $ in front of a string can make it a variable like $1. But $filename is easier for me to remember that this is a variable about the the file name. That's why I named it $filename. Can I do this? Or I can only use numbers for variables names in .bashrc, such as $1, $101, $9999?

Comment: @Counter10000, regular variables have names like `filename`, but the _arguments_ to a function or script show up in the so-called positional parameters, and they're the numbered ones, `$1`, `$2`, .... (they don't have names, unlike function parameters in real programming languages.)  see e.g. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions

Answer (score 0):

don't have to be so, you'd feel free and much benefit of it

```
ok() { set -f
if test -z "$2"
then
  grep -HPine "$1" -r --include=*.log --include=*.txt
else
  grep -HPine "$1" -r --include="$2"
fi
}

$ ok error test.txt
$ ok err test.txt
$ ok error
$ ok 'err|warn'
$ ok error logdata.*
```

the 3rd usage will find all lines having 'error' string in all files with log and txt extension across all directories in current directory
the 4th will find all lines having 'error' or 'warn' string in all files with log and txt extension across all directories in current directory
the 5th will find all lines having 'error' string in all files named logdata with any extension name across all directories in current directory